# An error occurred submitting the answer

Tags: support

I'm attempting to add an answer to this question:

[SQL CLR Trigger, How to make an assembly trusted due to transparent code call critical code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153370/sql-clr-trigger-how-to-make-an-assembly-trusted-due-to-transparent-code-call-cr)

The accepted answer is correct, but there is some additional information (too long for a comment) that I would like to add.  When I attempt to post my answer I get the error message "An error occurred submitting the answer."

This has been occurring for two days now, so I assume there is some content in my answer that is causing the error.  I can't post the content of my answer here (when I do I see the error message, "an error occurred submitting the question").  The answer contains a link to an MSDN article and some SQL code snippets, nothing out of the ordinary.

Is there any means to discover why my answer will not post?

[image: This is a screen shot of what I am attempting to post]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the details you are trying to add?

Comment: Have you tried posting just a part of the answer your wrote and then gradually extending it with edits?

Comment: I added a screen shot to the answer, thank you for the suggestion..

Comment: @TomRegan are you behind a corporate firewall that bans web forums? We've seen this happen in such cases before.

Comment: @TomRegan Try changing the URL from `http://stackoverflow.com` to `https://stackoverflow.com` and see if the post goes through. If so, it's most likely a firewall or overeager protection software on your end that's causing trouble.

Comment: https worked, thank you @AdamLear.  If you post your comment as an answer I'll select it.

Comment: In the past few days this site has real problems with submitting answers. Only 10 % of all attempts are successful. I have to edit or create new questions 100 times

Comment: @linuxoid: you appear to be talking about **questions**, not answers. Without any details about what happens on your side, we can't help you however. You'd have to post a new question and include what exactly happens when you try to post a question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This typically happens when there's an error like that, it means there's a firewall or overzealous protection software that's getting in the way and interpreting that post's text as malicious code.

You can check if that's the case by changing the URL from `http://stackoverflow.com` to `https://stackoverflow.com`. While we don't officially and fully support HTTPS yet, posting works fine. Traffic-scanning software can't see the actual contents, so if it is to blame, the post should go through just fine that way.

Comment: switching to https solved a persistent "An error occurred submitting the answer" posting error for me.

Comment: Too bad, it didn't help me.