# How can I ask a question with code involving SQL injection?

Tags: bug

I'm trying to ask a question about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) on Stack Overflow, but I think some sort of input validator is preventing me from submitting. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Offending post]

When I remove the lines that involve SQL injection, that endpoint returns `200 OK`.

Here is the error in the console. It looks like it is jQuery:

[image]

I suppose, now that I've written this up, I could just take a screenshot of my code?

Comment: what's the actual error?

Comment: I cannot submit the question.

Comment: Probably a network appliance in between you and Stack Overflow; most likely from your place of business.

Comment: Can we get the details of the failed request or other validation failure?

Comment: First, don't screenshot your code. It's highly frowned upon, for several reasons. Second, try [the answer posted here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298472/2607247) and see if it helps. It sounds like a similar case- And I feel like I've seen this exact scenario before but until I find it, at least maybe that answer can help you.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, I've added some details.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, can you clarify? My company might be reading the contents of the POST and rejecting?

Comment: @gwg Some companies use network appliances (that scan traffic and dump any traffic that could be malicious -- like SQL Injection). Theoretically if you post the question using `https://`, then they shouldn't be able to see the traffic and intercept it; but they also may be MITM certs; no way to be sure unless you try it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yeah, I asked the question using `https`, and it POST-ed fine. TIL.