# An error occurred submitting the edit

Tags: support, error-message

This is my question I can't edit or answer:

[Join string variables in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474454/join-string-variables-in-sql-server)

What I'm getting back after submit is this in red:

```
An error occurred submitting the edit.
```

Why is SO stubbornly refusing my edits?

**EDIT**

When I said SO is refusing edits, I meant SO client or server. I don't know whick side.

However, in Chrome I open dev tools and find this in console:

```
POST https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33474454/edit-submit/aaca2e2f-d991-44d5-8253-7b558d0c1b61 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Obviously there is no response from SO. How can I find if the question reached SO server or not? And should I be the one to investigate this at all?

Comment: How is SO refusing your edits if they aren't even making it to the servers in the first place?

Comment: SO isn't doing anything. The stubbornness lies squarely on your network's side I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you behind any network firewalls or proxies? That's usually the culprit for these errors, and sadly something outside of SO's control.

Comment: What I don't understand is that I was able to post a new question, but not edit the same question. I don't see how is that related to firewall or proxy.

Comment: They're different edit forms. If you hit the edit link on a post you get an inline editor since you have >2k rep. 'Ask a question' is a standalone page. Try opening the edit from the revision history. You'll get a standalone editor. Maybe some something about the ajaxy inline editor is blocked on your network. (Just speculation at this point, the submission may be exactly the same.)

Comment: @theB: thanks a bunch, that may be exactly the problem. I'll try posting from home and see what happens.

Comment: Try posting your edit from HTTPS rather than HTTP. This is _usually_ what helps with posting errors on anything SQL, as it usually turns out to be something on your local network seeing the SQL you're posting and blocking it, thinking it's an attack of sorts.

Comment: See [An error occurred submitting the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298413/an-error-occurred-submitting-the-answer) for instance. (Yes, that's an answer and not an edit, but it's likely the same cause as this has popped up for more than just answers.)

Comment: Looks like the edit-forms just randomly fails? It just happened to me - copied my changes, reloaded the page and tried again, and it worked. Rather than a network issue, this is more likely an authorization issue of some sort?