# In SQL code block: unable to save a `(*)` in some instances

Tags: support

In question *[How to translate syntax from SQL Server to Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472584/how-to-translate-syntax-from-sql-server-to-postgresql/43472804#43472804)* I have saved an answer.

In it I have an SQL code block where I used a `[*)` instead of `(*)`, because every time I tried to save it with a `(*)` I get a document save error. Is this a feature or known bug?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: I am behind a corporate firewall.

Comment: They probably have a "security" module that detects the SQL and prevents you from submitting the form.

Comment: Odd, I save SQL all the time.  it's just this occurrence where the subquery with the select count seems to be failing.

Comment: I was able to make the change. I hope that doesn't prevent you from making subsequent edits now :p

Comment: Interesting.  I'll keep in mind it could be the firewall.  I can usually refactor the SQL to get it to work but this was so basic I couldn't do that here.

Comment: TLS is your friend :D

Comment: TLA's aren't what's a TLS?

Comment: This has been asked before. The recommendation is to use HTTPS to post the change, this seems to fix the issue. See [An error occurred submitting the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298413/an-error-occurred-submitting-the-answer) and its linked posts.